# Smooth change background image, Chrome works but IE not

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I'm trying for several hours animates to change the background image for my site. When I tried it on Google Chrome browser, it was easy, but then I tried it in Internet Explorer and there it does not work. The same problem has also Mozilla Firefox. I am looking for some tutorials on how to do this in jQuery, but nothing does not work.

Please can you help me?

I would like to make animation work on every browser.

**HTML**

```
<div class="div">Text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6597309/images/button.png);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.div:hover {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6597309/images/hover.png);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3w7Wp/) of my project.

Comment: You know you can do that with gradients/box-shadow now, right? All depends on how far back you want to support IE. I would suggest doing this with css3 and creating a fallback for old IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this for all browser by adding another div that contains your hover image and fading that one in and out. It's more consistent and will work in all browsers. You will have to put your content in another div and give it a higher z-index, but it essentially solves your problem.

Your HTML would be this:

```
<div class="div">
    <div class="hover"></div>
    <div class="content">Content in here</div>
</div>
```

And heres the CSS:

```
.div {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6597309/images/button.png);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.div > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}    
.div > div.content {
    z-index: 2;
}
.div > div.hover{
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6597309/images/hover.png);
    opacity: 0;            
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;    
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.div:hover > div.hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You could even use jQuery to make it work in older browsers as well:

```
$(".hover").parent().mouseover(function(event){
    $(this).find(".hover").stop().animate({"opacity": 1});
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find(".hover").stop().animate({"opacity": 0});
});
```

Although when you do this, either check in Javascript if it supports CSS3 transitions and when it does, don't; do the script. It will take a heck of a long time to execute this with the value changing every frame in jQuery, and CSS trying to make every change last 0.4s...

Comment: I really thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time and trouble.